# how to print confusion matrix of keras Multi output?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, deep-learning

I have one question.
I want to print a confusion matrix.
my model is functional api of keras.
and 
model = Model(inputs=[data_input], outputs=[output_1, output_2])

output_1 = 9 classes
output_2 = 5 classes

**My multi-classification model**

```
data_input = Input(shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2]))

Conv1 = Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=4, padding='valid',  activation='relu', strides=1)(data_input)
Conv1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(Conv1)

Conv2 = Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=4, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(Conv1)
Conv2 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(Conv2)

Conv3 = Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=4, padding='valid', activation='relu', strides=1)(Conv2)
Conv3 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(Conv3)

Classification1 = LSTM(128, input_shape=(47, 50), return_sequences=False)(Conv3)
Classification2 = GRU(128, input_shape=(47, 50), return_sequences=False)(Conv3)

activity = Dense(9)(Classification1)
activity = Activation('softmax')(activity)

speed = Dense(5)(Classification2)
speed = Activation('softmax')(speed)

model = Model(inputs=[data_input], outputs=[activity, speed])

model.compile(loss= 'categorical_crossentropy' , optimizer='adam', metrics=[ 'accuracy' ])
print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(trainX, {'activation_1': trainY_Activity, 'activation_2': trainY_Speed},
          validation_data=(testX, {'activation_1': testY_Activity, 'activation_2': testY_Speed}),
          epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1, shuffle=False)
```

Comment: Once confusion matrix is essentialy 2D, for your multi classification case I can only think in these 2 approaches: make 2 confusion matrices, one for each output; OR combine all the possibilities of both classes (in this case 45 possibilites) and make the confusion matrix according to that.

Comment: Have a look here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html

you can use model.predict() to get y_predict.

Comment: Thanks. Mete Han Kahraman, Hemerson Tacon.
To  Mete Han Kahraman : ok. I will try.
To Hemerson Tacon : model.predict() can use only sequential() model.
ex) model = Sequential()
my model is non sequentail model.